# How to check mkusb version?

Tags: mkusb

There are no `--version`  or `-v`  options, and the command not say (!) its version.

PS: `man mkusb` *is reliable?* but is ambiguous, say "dus(8)" (not `mkusb`) and at end say "version 12.0.0" but it is not obvious is a software or documentation version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### mkusb version 12.0.5 works like this

Run the following command

```
mkusb -v
```

and you get a choice, which version to select, and then you will get the version number of that version.

[image]

Sorry about the manual, it is not quite up to date, so

```
man mkusb
```

will display an older version number. Thanks for the heads up, I will spend some time to update the manual.

### Edit: mkusb -v works as expected in version 12.0.6

The behaviour of `mkusb -v` is improved now. You made me upload mkusb version 12.0.6. Thanks @Peter Krauss, you helped to improve mkusb :-)

[image]

Comment: PS: sorry, @sudodus is the `dus` developer (nio-wiklund)!?  Supposing that you, Thanks a lot by your work!  (and redo my comments)

Comment: *Suggestion 1*: to understand what an "standard user" expect with `mkusb -v` (what "make sense"), is to see a version number or a list of tool-version items. Anything different is strange for "standard user"  perception  ... So ideal is to display a list of tool-version items.

Comment: *Suggestion 2*: add at version-list the `mkusb` description: *"after v11 it is not a tool, it is only a selector of tools"*... So, say that  "the real tool" is `dus` and not `mkusb`.

Comment: I am uploading a new version, 12.0.6, where `mkusb-select` alias `mkusb` is modified to display the versions directly, and where the manual is also upgraded. You find it in `ppa:mkusb/unstable` according to the following link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui#from_the_unstable_PPA - Please test it and tell me, if there is something else, that needs to be improved.

Comment: I uploaded the new version before I saw these two suggestions. I think the first one is already fixed, and I can fix the second one in a later version. But now I'm waiting for you to add some new suggestions ...

Comment: You can simply add the new PPA: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/unstable`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55420/discussion-between-sudodus-and-peter-krauss).

Comment: I try... PERFECT!  `mkusb -v`  shows a list of versions!  "mkusb-dus:   dus 12.0.5
mkusb-11:  mkusb 11.2.1
mkusb-nox: mkusb-nox 11.1.9
mkusb-bas: mkusb version 7.4.2"

Answer (score 0):

You should get the version number by simply running `mkusb` as shown below. My version for example is shown as **11.0.5**

```
    mkusb
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
start [mkusb 11.0.5] @ 2017-03-15 EAT 12:01:18 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Usage:
sudo -H /usr/sbin/mkusb
```

Comment: ??!  Not works for me.  the first line is 
`Usage: mkusb [input-file]      # optional parameter`... and show letter options.

Comment: Alright run "sudo apt-get - -purge remove mkusb"and reinstall it again by running the following commands one by one "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa" , "sudo apt-get update" then lastly "sudo apt-get install mkusb"

Comment: hum... See my answer to compare "fresh versions"... My instalation was the complete one,  `sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi`.

Comment: mkusb 11.0.5 is an old version. If you are running a supported version of Ubuntu, you are able to update/upgrade it via the standard method for installed programs. Otherwise, please tell me which distro and version you are running, and I can suggest how to get a current version of mkusb.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workawound,

`man mkusb | tail | grep version`. The result is something as

```
                GPLv3: GNU GPL version ...
version 12.0.0              December 29, 2016             dus(8)
```

In this case "12.0.0".

Comment: Sorry, the manual is not up to date. Thanks for the heads up. I will fix it ...